# Regex not matching in Java Program

Tags: java, regex

I've built the following [regex](https://regexr.com/3mod8). This matches the function call `fn-bea:uuid()`

It obviously matches the function, but when integrating it into my java program:

```
xqueryFileContent.replaceAll("(fn\\-bea:uuid\\(\\))", "0");
```

the function is not replaced. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: I can't make out if `\\-` is escaping `-` or if you want to match `\-`. Please clarify it by giving the exact string to replace it.

Comment: @ArunGowdru I want to replace `fn-bea:uuid()` with 0

Comment: You need to assign the replaced value back to `xqueryFileContent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use a regex here. Just `String#replace` for simple string search-replace:

```
xqueryFileContent = xqueryFileContent.replace("fn-bea:uuid()", "0");
```

---

If you must use a regex then use `Pattern.quote` to quote all special characters:

```
xqueryFileContent = xqueryFileContent.replaceAll( 
  Pattern.quote("fn-bea:uuid()"), "0" );
```

Comment: In this testcase there's just one fn-bea:uuid(), but there can be multiple. replaceAll wants a pattern as parameter.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to escape your `-` :

```
xqueryFileContent.replaceAll("(fn-bea:uuid\\(\\))", "0");
```

Comment: Not working, and why do I need to double escape, single escape of `\\` would also return `\\` no?

Comment: @0x45 I updated my answer, I thought you wanted to match a backslash.

Comment: @0x45 Are you reassigning your Java variable? `xqueryFileContent = xqueryFileContent.replaceAll("(fn-bea:uuid\\(\\))", "0");`

Comment: `-` is a special character for regex, yes it needs escaping

Comment: @kutschkem Inside `[]` yes, not outside

Answer (score -1):

You must use the result of `replaceAll`:

```
xqueryFileContent = xqueryFileContent.replaceAll("(fn\\-bea:uuid\\(\\))", "0");
```